# Uploading progress not working on android titanium?

Tags: android, file-upload, titanium

I am doing android application using titanium studio. I cannot find anything recent on this but I am unable to get the onsendstream XHR event to work when uploading a file. I looked at the docs and it doesnt say apple only. Its work on iOS.  can any one help me. Thanks in advance.

```
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr.onsendstream = function(e){

    Ti.API.info('ONSENDSTREAM - PROGRESS: ' + e.progress);
};
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    Ti.API.info('ONLOAD - PROGRESS: ');
}
xhr.onerror = function(e) {
    Ti.API.info('ONERROR- PROGRESS: ');
}
xhr.open('POST', URL);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.send({data});
```

Answer (score 0):

This image uploader would work for both android and iOS and it has a progress bar too

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/titanium-mobile-build-an-image-uploader--mobile-8860

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to my use of onsendstream event , it only work in a **real device**.

In simulator or emulator, **e.progress** will have value only 0 and 1 and not intermediate values.

Comment: i am using android real device not simulator.

Comment: what is the value you get in :-

**Ti.API.info('ONSENDSTREAM - PROGRESS: ' + e.progress);**

Comment: that event is not trigger. That is the problem

Comment: Have you checked in titanium q & a , there are many question for it. Check following links : [tag/onsendstream](http://developer.appcelerator.com/questions/tag/onsendstream) and [question](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/134363/xhr-put-file-upload-onsendstream-event). I think you must also try checking **ondatastream** property once.